# Implementing news feed on GAE - Should I use Prospective Search?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an issue i'm struggling with for some time now. Im trying to implement a news feed feature in my app using GAE cloud endpoints and java. The common concept is of followers and followees, where an action of a followee can be seen by his followers. A new follower should also see his followees past actions, not only from the time he started following.

I made a few tries with the following components. Each try worked great but was lacking something:

1. On each user action i added a 'log' entity into the datastore with the user id included. When a user was displaying his news feed i just queried for all those entities by their user ids according to the user's followees list. Everything was fine until i realized that a 'IN' query cannot be cursored. So this option was gone.
2. On this try, which is also the current state of the application, im using the Search API. Upon every user action im not storing a 'log' entity into the datastore anymore but a document into a search index. Complex queries can be cursored here and the world is smiling again. But... im not too sure that, billing wise, this is a smart descision. It seems that the costs of searching/adding/deleting documents along side the [documented](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Java_Search_API_quotas_and_pricing) daily limitations is making the whole thing a bit too sketchy.
3. The next try should be Prospective Search API. From what i'm reading in the [documents](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/prospectivesearch/) it seems the right component to pick for that purpose. Unfortunately, the documentation is really poor and give very little examples. Also the billing information is unclear.

So im asking for the advice of the stackoverflow community. Can you please advise me about this matter ? and if Prospective Search is the right option to choose, can you please provide some clear sample java code that uses cloud endpoints?

**EDIT :** Just to emphasize the main design requirement here - The news feed feature need to have the ability to fetch sorted followees actions using a cursor (in order avoid querying the whole batch).

Answer (score 2):

Use a pull-aggregate-per-follower model: periodically (or on demand) query all followees actions once and then cache them inside a dedicated per-follower entity. Remember the time of last query, so next time you just query from that point on (assuming actions can not be added/changed to the past times).

This will give you the following features (and limitations):

1. If query is on-demand, than you will not need to query for users that are inactive.
2. Since the query is "new-only" (looks for new actions only), it would cost you nothing if it returned zero results.
3. You will only query each followee actions per follower once. After that all recent actions would be cached inside one entity and loaded into memory with one `get`. This should be a substantial cost and time saving.
4. You could sort/filter actions in memory any way you wish.

Limitations:

1. Entities have a 1MB limit, so there is a max no of actions that you can cache in one entity. So you will either need to limit caching of recent actions per user or spread out action caching over multiple entities.
2. You will need to use IN query over followees (max 30) and also use parallel threads to achieve decent performance. This could easily hit 3-5 seconds when querying over 1000-2000 followees. Also, you could easily hit RPC limit (aka max concurrent API calls) per instance when serving multiple users at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i understand you correctly, you are basically saying that i need to keep duplicate 'users actions' data. Once in a central datastore repository, where i will keep a log of all actions, and a duplicate for a user's followees actions (which will (and its aggregates) be populated on-demand). I can see some significant drawbacks in this solution : 1. This could potentially increase the datastore size manyfold. 2. What happens if a user is unfollowing someone ? 3. Your limitation no. 2 sounds like a deal breaker to me.

Comment: You are basically trying to recreate Twitter model on AppEngine - there are bound to be some corners cut. 1. Yes, in this case you trade data size for speed and cost of access. Note that DB storage is cheap. 2. Delete actions from cache on next update. 3. RPC limit is a problem that you can approach from different angles: limit number of friends (people followed by a user), limit number of parallel queries (= slower response for users that follow a lot of people), perform queries async (via task queue), partition queries (do queries for close friend synchronously, the rest async), etc..

Comment: I really appreciate the time you're spending on this. But to tell you the truth, i dont see a significant added value with this solution over the Search API. The storage space each user's actions takes, multiplied by the number of followers each user has, will grow exponentially as the app users base will grow. To that i need to add a large scale query operations in order to aggregate new followees actions (not true `it would cost you nothing if it returned zero results`. see [https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#cost_resource](documentation)), ...

Comment: I did a rough breakdown of the costs of your solution with an example of one user with 50 followees and an aggregation of 20 actions each one. Im igonring the main 'actions' repository size since this is equivalent in cost to the Search API index size.
1. Saving users actions to central repository - Write ops - 50 x 20 x 10 write ops (rough estimation).
2. Query for aggregation - Read ops - a. 50 x 20 x 1 read per entity retrieved. b. ? (unknown number of total entities in main 'actions' repository) x 1 read. c. 1 read of the Cached per-follower entity.

Comment: 3. Saving Cached per-follower entity - 4 write ops (rough estimation).
4. Cached per-follower entities total size - 50 x 20 x 300 bytes (example size of a user action) = 300KB.

Lets assume we have 100,000 actions in our repository (very low number). The total is : 0.071$.

The Search API will cost for the same scenario - 
1. Adding Documents to Indexes - 50 x 20 x 300 bytes.
2. Complex Query - 1.
Total : 0.00066$

Comment: Do you agree ? Or am i missing something here ?

Comment: We don't use Search API so I can't really say. OTOH it seems your example is not representative. What if a user follows 1000 or more other users (as is the case with FB or Twitter). Will this work with Search API? Will you be able to do a search with OR parameter over 1000s different values (usernames)?

Comment: About the cost - it heavily depends on the usage pattern as Datastore and Search APIs have quite different cost models. Proposed DS-based model mainly costs when saving data and doing aggregation, afterwards queries are cheap (only one get). Search-based model is cheap upfront (no document saving costs, only storage costs), but complex queries are expensive (10x the cost of DB queries). In your case you seem to perform full aggregation but only one query. In real life I feel a particular usage would be different - people reloading pages performing many queries over the same data.

Comment: I searched really carefully the Search API documentation and couldnt find any limitations on their complex queries. So, on paper, there should be no problem using OR over 1000s values. Secondly, regarding your second comment, im not sure im clear on that. In order for a user to have a strongly consistent news feed data he will have to query the main repository each time and see if there are new actions. IMHO i cannot avoid this check for aggregations (unless i want to cut corners). And according to the link i posted on my 3rd comment above this query can be costly even if it returned 0 results

Comment: I guess the 2 upvotes and half of the bounty were given for originality, cause i dont see a real benefit with this solution in terms of cost and performance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question correctly - you want to implement a news feed into your application and allow users to follow each other. The new followers need to be able to see the users actions. I am sure there are multiple other ways of solving this problem, but I will attempt to help you out by providing a solution that makes use of JAVA JDO to access the datastore.

I would first design the [entity relationships in JDO](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships) as follows:

```
1 User to many actions.
1 User to many followers (User).
1 User to many following (User).
```

Here are simple JDO classes:

User Class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String userId; // Google unique user ID, could also store user email. 

    @Persistent
    private Set<Key> actions;

    @Persistent
    private Set<Key> followers;

    @Persistent
    private List<Key> following;

    public User(Key key, String userId) {
        this.key       = key;
        this.userId    = userId;
        this.actions   = new HashSet<Key>();
        this.followers = new HashSet<Key>();
        this.following = new HashSet<Key>();  
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public void addAction(Key actionKey) {
        this.actions.add(actionKey);
    }

    public void addActions(Set<Key> actionKeys) {
        this.actions.addAll(actionKeys);
    }

    public Set<Key> getActions() {
        return this.actions;
    }

    public void addFollower(Key followerKey) {
        this.followers.add(followerKey);
    }

    public void addFollowers(Set<Key> followerKeys) {
        this.followers.addAll(followerKeys);
    }

    public Set<Key> getFollowers() {
        return this.followers;
    }

    public void addFollowing(Key followingKey) {
        this.following.add(followingKey);
    }

    public void addAllFollowing(Set<Key> followingKeys) {
        this.following.addAll(followingKeys);
    }

    public Set<Key> getFollowing() {
        return this.following;
    }

}
```

Action Class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Action {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    Date date;

    @Persistent
    private String title;    

    public Action(Key key, String title) {

        this.key   = key;
        this.title = title;

        this.date  = new Date(); // date of creation (now). 

    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

}
```

The Action class makes use of a Date property, you can refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) for applicable data types in the datastore. When an action is created, [a Date object is allocated and initialized so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

In my example above I linked the entities by their Keys, you could instead link them by their classes as follows:

```
List<Action> actions;
```

The relationship in my example is one of an unowned one-to-many relationship, perhaps it should be owned one-to-many. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships) for your to take a look and perhaps decide which would be best for your solution.

Once the relationships have been defined, you can [create your endpoint classes around the JDO model classes](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities). This will create basic api methods. You might want to change the endpoint class methods to suit your needs, for example change the way an action is created. A basic example would be to create the key from the actions title as follows (ActionEnpoint.java):

```
...
@ApiMethod(name = "insertAction")
public Action insertAction( @Named("title") String title ) {

    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Action.class.getSimpleName(), title);

    Action action = null;

    try {
        action = new Action(key, title);
        pm.makePersistent(action);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

    return action;

}
...
```

If you want to, you can add a method to your UserEndpoint class to query the datastore and return all actions belonging to that user and per date using the [datastore query objects](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries).

You need to add a method to your UserEndpoint class that allows you to add an action to that user, here is a simple example:

```
...
@ApiMethod(name = "addActionToUser")
public Achiever addActionToUser(
    @Named("userId") String userId, 
    @Named("actionTitle") String actionTitle) {

    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

    Key userKey   = KeyFactory.createKey(User.class.getSimpleName(), userId);
    Key actionKey = KeyFactory.createKey(Action.class.getSimpleName(), actionTitle);

    User user = null;

    try {   
        user = (User) pm.getObjectById(User.class, userKey);
        user.addAction(actionKey);
        pm.makePersistent(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } 

    return user;
}
...
```

Once all of the above is complete you can easily get the list of actions per user by calling the getUser method in your UserEndpoint class, which returns a User object. You can then call [ReturnedUserObject].getActions(). A new follower can now view all of the "followees" actions by just calling the api method to get that "followees" object and get his/her actions. You can then just sort the actions by date or however you envision it.

I hope I understood your question correctly, I was unsure about the first component you mentioned, but it seemed as though you got your relationships mixed up. I hope this solution points you in the right direction at least :).

If you need any additional help or clarification, or my answer was completely off point to what you were looking for then please let me know.

Kind regards,
Miki

Comment: @Miki First of all thank you for the detailed answer. Secondly, the main issue here was not putting the data into the datastore but querying for it in a way that i will not have to fetch EVERYTHING in one batch. Meaning, using cursors. So, just in case i missed something in your answer, can you tell me how do you query "followees" actions (sorted by date) and using a cursor ?

Comment: @AsafK Ah, I understand, I apologise, I did not mean to sound condescending, after re-reading your question it makes sense that you have already been storing data properly :). Regardless, in the generated endpoint classes, there should be an api method that will list your data (listUser or listAction). The method takes two parameters, a cursorString and an integer limit. The method returns a list of actions (or users) by making use of a cursor. You should also be able to query by date, I have never done this before but take a look at the docs on querying datastore for more info :).

Comment: @Miki As i said in my question, 'IN' query in GAE datastore cannot use cursors. see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Limitations_of_cursors). And a query to fetch all "followees" action need to use 'IN'.

Comment: @AsafK Hmm... I see. I would not be able to comment any further then. Would be interesting to know the solution to this, however.